# Regex to identify paragraph in vim consisting of exactly 1 row

Tags: regex, vim

Input

```
row 1
row 2

row 1

row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4
row 5
row 6

row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4
row 5
```

The regex should only return the paragraph consisting only of row 1

```
row 1
```

I tried something like v/(\n\n)+/d for the first, but didn't get it to work.

Comment: Do you want to remove all paragraphs containing 2 or more lines?

Comment: In this case yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
:%s/\v\n*.+(\n.+)+\n*/\r/g
```

This command replaces all occurrences in the file of the following

- `\v` - enables very magic mode to avoid escaping hell
- `\n*` - matches zero or more line breaks
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars (a  non-empty line)
- `(\n.+)+` - matches one or more non-empty lines
- `\n*` - zero or more newlines.

The replacement is a line break, `\r`, to avoid line concatenation if there are several matches.